# Django Filters - Edit queryset based on slug from url

Tags: django, python-3.x, filter, django-queryset, django-filters

So I have a simple model called Pages. Every Page belongs to a certain category, since this is a ForeignKey relation, a Page can only belong to a single category.

Besides categories we also use tags to furthermore filter the different pages.

We use a category view to display all pages belonging to a certain category, easy peasy.

The thing is, we use django-filters to filter the pages by selecting different tags. The list of tags is increasing by the amount of pages. Therefore I would like to only show related tags to the category.

## urls.py

```
path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.PageByCategoryView.as_view(), name='page_by_category'),
```

## views.py

```
class PageByCategoryView(FilterView):
    logger.info("Category view is called")
    model = Page
    filterset_class = PageByCategoryFilter
    strict = False
    queryset = Page.published_objects.all()
    template_name = 'pages/page_by_category.html'
```

## filters.py

```
   class PageByCategoryFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
        tags = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
            queryset=Tag.objects.filter(page__category_id='2'), <-- actually works!
            conjoined=True,
            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        )

        class Meta:
            model = Page
            fields = [
                'tags__slug'
            ]
```

So the tags used in the filter actually get filtered by page__category_id = 2, this is exactly what I want to achieve though I want to do this dynamically. I tried to define the qs like so;

```
@property
def qs(self):
        queryset = super(PageByCategoryFilter, self).qs
        current_category = self.request.GET.get('category_slug')
        if current_category:
            logger.info("Current category is in url")
            return queryset.filter(category__slug=current_category)
        return queryset
```

This just doesn't seem to be working, how can i get the current_category from the url?

Alright, what I did below does actually work but it look kinda hackish..
Doe anyone have a better answer on solving this issue?

```
def category_filter(request):
    path = request.path
    category_slug = re.sub('\/+', r'', path)
    current_category = category_slug
    return Tag.objects.filter(page__category__slug=current_category).distinct()
```

With best regards,

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Your original view function should be able to take a parameter `category_slug` where the category slug of the URL is passed in, like [in this example from the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#specifying-defaults-for-view-arguments) (notice how `num` is declarad as an `int` in the URL and then passed as an argument to `page`):

In `urls.py`

```py
    path('blog/page<int:num>/', views.page),
```

In your view function

```py
def page(request, num=1):
    ...
```

If you're using Django REST, you should be able to get the URL parameter your `kwargs` member attribute, [like so](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-url):

In `urls.py`

```py
url('^purchases/(?P<username>.+)/$', PurchaseList.as_view()),
```

In your view classes:

```py
class PurchaseList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the purchases for
        the user as determined by the username portion of the URL.
        """
        username = self.kwargs['username']  # this is what you're after
        return Purchase.objects.filter(purchaser__username=username)
```